# RequireJS: Different count of dependencies and params at callback function

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-define

I have legacy code and a module definition like this:

```
define(["a", "b", "c", "d"], function(a, b, c) {
    ...
});
```

You can see that there are more dependencies than actual params that we are using at module.

Does it make any sense? I think module **"d"** is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This only means that module "d" (or, to be more precise, the result of calling "d"'s factory function) won't be passed as a parameter (e.g. `d`) to the function, so it won't be available inside it.

It's possible that module "d" executes some code with side-effects so removing it could potentially change how you application behaves (i.e. break something).

Comment: And do you think it's normal behavior? It looks not intuitive.

Comment: Nobody stops you from adding the "missing" `d` parameter, but it would be unused inside the function - depending on your JS linter configuration this could be considered a style violation.

Comment: I found that d is defined globally. So, it means that I'm waiting while d is loaded, after it will pollute global scope and it's possible to use it at callback.

Answer (score 1):

Having a define with a list of dependencies longer than the list of parameters passed declared on the factory function of a `define` call is a common occurrence with RequireJS, and not a sign that anything is wrong with the code.

For instance, when using jQuery with plugins, it is completely normal to have something like:

```
define(['jquery', 'jquery.foo'], function ($) {
    // Use the foo plugin.
    $('p').foo(...)
```

where 'jquery.foo' is a module implementing a jQuery plugins. jQuery plugins install themselves as methods on the `jQuery` object (which we get as `$` in the code above). When such plugins are loaded with RequireJS, they quite often have no useful *module* value. If changed the function above to `function ($, foo)`, the `foo` parameter would most likely be `undefined`.

Note that none of this *entails* leaking globals. If `jquery.foo` is written so that it registers as a proper AMD module then it does not depend on a `jQuery` (or `$` global) and thus `jQuery.noConflict(true)` could have been called before it loads to remove the globals that jQuery creates by default.